# VC++: when building with /MD: unresolved externals like _memset & _terminate & ___vcrt_initialize

Tags: visual-c++, linker, linker-errors, unresolved-external, crt

***edit: I finally was able to resolve all unresolved symbols - see my answer below. However the behavior of the MS tools remains mysterious and not like documented.***

I have an ANT project, that uses the Visual Studio (C++) 2022 toolchain on Win 10 to build.
So there is no VS project - every setting is done via ANT.

I want an exe and a dll sharing the same CRT. So therefore I use the /MD compiler switch.

Currently I struggle with the dll.
Unfortunately, at the end I get many unresolved externals, i.e. `_floor`, `_memset`, `_memcpy`,
and also `_terminate`, which is referenced by LIBCMT.LIB (*is this a hint already?*).

With the `/VERBOSE:LIB` linker switch I analysed the libs that are used, which are the following:

```
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\rpcns4.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\rpcrt4.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\winspool.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\shell32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\ole32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\Ws2_32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\Psapi.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86\IPHlpApi.Lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\delayimp.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\msvcprt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\MSVCRT.lib:
```

`msvcrt.lib` seems to be the suitable one according to [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-170#c-runtime-lib-files). And it obviously was picked by the linker automatically.
However I don't understand under which circumstances the other mentioned libs should be picked: `ucrt.lib` and `vcruntime.lib`.

Using `dumpbin /symbols "..."  | find /i " _memset"` I can see, that neither
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86\ucrt.lib` nor
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\vcruntime.lib` contain it.
But I can find it in `libvcruntime.lib`:

```
> dumpbin /symbols "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86\libvcruntime.lib"  | find /i " _memset"
011 00000000 SECT6  notype ()    External     | _memset
```

But this should be the static one, so not suitable for me, right?

Any hint how to get the missing functions??

Answer (score 1):

At first, the `LIBCMT.lib` you see in my question resulted from an old object, that still was compiled with /MT. After I updated this object, the `LIBCMT.lib` disappeared from linker output.

---

`vcruntime.lib` indeed contained symbols like `_memset, _memcpy`.
And `ucrt.lib` contained symbols like `__imp__calloc`, `_terminate` & `_floor`.

The exported symbols contained in the libs could finally be viewed by `dumpbin /linkermember:1`.
(`dumpbin /exports` did not show e.g. `__imp__calloc` in `ucrt.lib`.)

Although `msvcrt.lib` was picked by the linker automatically, I **had to specify `vcruntime.lib` & `ucrt.lib` manually**. (*Does anyone know why?*)

---

After that I was left with the following **11 unresolved** symbols:

```
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_initialize referenced in function ___scrt_initialize_crt
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_uninitialize referenced in function ___scrt_initialize_crt
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_uninitialize_critical referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_critical
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_thread_attach referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_attach
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_thread_detach referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_attach
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __is_c_termination_complete referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_c
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_initialize referenced in function ___scrt_initialize_crt
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_uninitialize referenced in function ___scrt_uninitialize_crt
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_uninitialize_critical referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_critical
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_thread_attach referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_attach
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_thread_detach referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_detach
```

This seems to be the same problem like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124505/which-library-contains-is-c-termination-complete). It has no real good answer (currently), but a comment there refers to [this MS community question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92ad53c5-22c1-4905-82a2-b0f1d68dbfc8/unresolved-symbols-moving-c-mfcbased-application-to-vs2015-from-vs2008?forum=vcgeneral). There the solution was to **remove the `/ENTRY:myEntryPoint`**.

---

Following this I end up with the **unresolved external `_DllMainCRTStartup`**.

I could not find this symbol in `vcruntime.lib` as [the MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior) stated, however I found **`__DllMainCRTStartup@12`** in `msvcrt.lib`.
`vcruntime.lib` was already used; and `msvcrt.lib` was also already used.  The sticking point is:
`msvcrt.lib` contains the `__stdcall` variant of the function – what I need is the `__cdecl` variant.

So I decided to build a little **bridge** like this:

```
extern "C" BOOL __stdcall _DllMainCRTStartup(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL, 
    DWORD fdwReason,    
    LPVOID lpvReserved );

extern "C" BOOL __cdecl DllMainCRTStartup(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpvReserved )  // reserved
{
      return _DllMainCRTStartup( hinstDLL,  
                                 fdwReason,     
                                 lpvReserved ); 
}
```

---

This linked without error, however I got a **warning**

```
warning LNK4086: entrypoint '_DllMainCRTStartup' is not __stdcall with 12 bytes of arguments; image may not run
```

which brought me to the solution to specify the `msvcrt.lib` function as entrypoint:

**`/ENTRY:__DllMainCRTStartup@12`**

I deleted my bridge and made an [ordinary DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior?view=msvc-170#initialize-a-dll).

---

which finally linked fine.

---

*So all that's left to do is to explain this unexpected behavior:*

1. *Why does the linker choose `_DllMainCRTStartup` as default entrypoint, but does not comply with its calling convention?

   (Remember: The unresolved external `_DllMainCRTStartup` disappears when I simply specify the (already existing) function `__DllMainCRTStartup@12` as entrypoint.)*
2. *Why does the linker miss those 11 unresolved externals, while they are no problem when I simply specify another function (`__DllMainCRTStartup@12`) as entrypoint.*
3. *[Where do those 11 symbols reside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54124505/16049096), if I would indeed use my own entry function?*